# allowing Users to post Iframe videos

Tags: ruby, git, post, iframe

am currently trying to recreate tumblr as a little way of learning ruby.
i have hit a road block trying to allow users to be able to post iframe links into a post.

i have tried making a new form-group to try pass in a users input of an iframe url but no i'm definitely not in the right place

my git repo is https://github.com/harrison1234/vews_app

very new to ruby and have been searching around on stack overflow but finding it hard to connect peoples suggestions with my file types

Comment: What does the ``git`` tag have to do with your question?

Comment: sorry, just came up with a suggested tag. guessing you dont know the answer to my question